# How to connect SpringBoot application inside Docker to outside PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, docker, spring-boot

I have Java SpringBoot Web-application working on host machine. Application connects to PostgreSQL database. All works well. OS - Ubuntu 18.

Now i need to move application in Docker container, except for PostgreSQL which will remain on host machine.

I installed Docker, rise up container, but my app inside docker cannot connect to PostgreSQL database with default settings (localhost).

Here is my **application.properties** file:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/webdemodb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Here is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM java:8
WORKDIR /
ADD target/webaccount-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
RUN fc-cache -f -v
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I read about Docker's networking but didn't find solution. What i need to setup?

Comment: You have to expose port 5432 as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: You have to use `host` network for your application

Comment: Mohammad LB, as i understood, it is no need to expose ports because of they translates as is.

Answer (score 1):

For simple usage i've just applied the next option when running container:

```
--network="host"
```

Full command:

```
docker run -d -p 9000:8080 --network="host" --name webaccount webaccount:1.0
```